# Redirecting pages via .htaccess from .php to Wordpress extension

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I recently switched my website over to Wordpress. The link structure on the old site was www.example.com/contact.php but now it is www.example.com/contact/. I want **all incoming** links to be redirected to www.example.com/contact/ (or whatever page it is). Someone recently helped me out with this and the .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /(.*)\.php($|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-login
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

It works to a certain extent. First, I have a custom contact form (from the Custom Contact Forms plugin) and it won't submit the form. Second, when I try and update a page it just takes me to the posts page. Is there something else I should be excluding besides wp-login? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

All of the code for creating new pages and posts, and updating old pages and posts, is in `wp-admin` so I suspect you need to add that to the list?

So the first part of your script becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /(.*)\.php($|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]
```

Of course, if you have non-standard folder names, amend as appropriate

Comment: I'm completely new to this, but it seems like its just skipping the [OR] part of it.